# Virtualbox install help

Tags: raspbian, emulation

I have been trying to install Oracle Virtual box in raspbian, but when I follow Oracle's tutorial, I get the error:

W: Failed to fetch http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists       /saucy/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'contrib/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

I know that this means the raspi can't get the file, but is there any other way to install it?

Comment: I doubt Oracle provides VirtualBox binaries for ARM, in this case for good reasons as well (SD wear, very limited resources).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run Virtualbox on the Pi because it is only available for i386 and amd64 and will not run on the Pi CPU.